# Org-Mode ignore pagebreak latex cmds in HTML export

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've an org mode file with explicit page breaks using the \pagebreak latex in the file. However if I export it to HTML, I get the literal \pagebreak in the exported file. Is there a way to tell HTML export to ignore such lines?

thanks
SJ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might try wrapping in Begin and End Latex's like this:

```
* This is a heading

#+Begin_Latex
\pagebreak
#+End_Latex

* Second heading
```

Comment: Depending on the version of org mode that the OP is using, this might have to be written as #+BEGIN_EXPORT latex ... #+END_EXPORT. Org mode 9 will require this.

Comment: Thanks! Should've have remembered that :(